# Multiple inner Joins with tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried following SQL query,

```
Select * from Shippers 
Inner Join Orders
ON Shippers.ShipperID =  Orders.ShipperID
Inner join OrderDetails
ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
```

but I'm getting following error :

***"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Shippers.ShipperID=Orders.ShipperID Inner join OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID=OrderDetails.OrderID'."***

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Have you altered your query at all for this question or is it posted EXACTLY the same as the one that generates the error?

Comment: No I dint alter anything. Everything was as it is. .

Comment: The query you have posted is a valid MySQL query and will not cause the error you are seeing.  Something else is going on here.  Is this part of a larger query?  Are you running this query from code or directly in MySQL?

Comment: No it is separate query.  I tried this query with w3schools.com. . Even though I'm getting same error

Comment: I would suggest creating an SQLFiddle to show that your query is failing so that we can help you figure this out. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Can you show us your tables that you use in this query? Best way will be doing a screenshot in phpmyadmin

Comment: This is a valid SQL query. Thus there is something else wrong with the environment you are running it in. Are the column names appropriate? Are you using and / or connected to the right datatabase? Is the datatype of the columns compatible? Do you have special characters hidden in your query somehow? Dig into environmental / schema issues, because your syntax is just fine.

Comment: Showing the tables won't help.  That is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the ON condition inside parentheses?

Is it possible the issue is due to having the same column name from multiple tables? Try just selecting individual columns, instead of *
e.g.

```
Select Shippers.ShipperID
from Shippers
Inner Join Orders
On (Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.ShipperID)
```

Have you tried removing one of the tables to see if the error only come up when you add the second table in? In other words does the following query work?

```
Select * from Shippers 
Inner Join Orders
ON (Shippers.ShipperID = Orders.ShipperID)
```

Is it possible you have some unprintable ascii characters hiding in there somewhere? What editor are you using?  what environment?